# Can I track a person from where they're coming from and where they go afterwards for my website?

Tags: google-analytics

I was wondering if you know if Google Analytics can track not just where the visitor was coming from, but also where he/she went afterwards. I have a mailing list setup on my blog and I would like to know if the users from Google went to my subscribe list.

I have outbound code tracking code from Google analytics on my  tags, but I'm not sure if it does 100% what I want. I just set it up like 12 hours ago so hopefully GA will update quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asynchronous Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
    _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent(category, action);
    setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100);
  }
</script>
```

Traditional (ga.js) Code
This should be placed after the standard tracking code snippet, to ensure the tracking object is loaded and retrievable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
  try {
    var pageTracker=_gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXX-X");
    pageTracker._trackEvent(category, action);
    setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
  }catch(err){}
}
</script>
```

Next, revise outbound links to call the new function without first following the link.
For example, to log every click on a particular link to www.example.com, you would use the _trackEvent() method in the link's  tag:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'example.com');return false;">
```

Stolen from:
[How do I manually track clicks on outbound links?](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55527)

Answer (score 1):

No. Not reliably.  You get the referer from an HTTP header, there is no equivalent in the other direction.

Comment: The only way you can do it for the other direction is if they're leaving the site from a link they click on yours.